# React useEffect depedencies warning eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to run a function inside useEffect,My code was work perfectly but I got a warning from eslint.

```js
const {
    error: { setErrorHolder },
  } = useNotification();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      setErrorHolder({ statusCode: 404, isAppError: true });
    }
  }, []);
```

[image]

In this example, I use the ReactQuery library for fetching.

```js
const { refetch } = useQuery('example');

  useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
  }, []);
```

[image]

Is there a better solution for this case? Thank you.

Comment: Why not just add the dependencies to the array(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You call refetch inside useEffect. That causes eslint (Rule of hooks) raises the issue since eslint doesn't know that "refetch" is never change.

To fixed:

- simply, add refetch to dependencies array as the suggestion
- if you're sure that "refetch" is never change source, just disable eslint rule using the syntax

```js
useEffect(...your effect...,
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[])
```

Comment: Is there a better solution than disable eslint?

Comment: The better solution is to add refetch to the dependency array you pass to useEffect, just as the warning says.

Comment: The first one is simply and best solution. Use the second approach if you know how exactly the useQuery works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the dependency to the array you pass to useEffect.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    setErrorHolder({ statusCode: 404, isAppError: true });
  }
}, [setErrorHolder]);
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  refetch();
}, [refetch]);
```